# InDesign: Remove all overrides for one paragraph style

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles

I have a 350-page document in which the text is formatted as [Basic Paragraph] and for which the justification is overridden. I need to remove paragraph overrides for [Basic Paragraph] leaving the character styles alone and leaving other paragraph styles alone.

I know I can click in each paragraph, then click [Basic Paragraph] to remove the override.  That's over 1,500 application of two clicks.

Is there a way to make such a change for an entire document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a *Find/Change* like this:

[image]

Leave *Find what* and *Change to* empty. In both *Find Format* and *Change Format*, click the small *Specify attributes to find* button and set *Paragraph Style* to *[Basic Paragraph]*.

<sub>(As a side note I will advice against using *[Basic Paragraph]* in your documents. It has some quirks which can be very annoying for example when trying to reuse paragraph styles in other documents.)</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the caution.   This time I didn't get to decide.

Comment: And thanks for the answer.  You have saved me an enormous amount of trouble!